# Check if point is within rectangle (all given by Longitutde / Latitude on Earth (Sphere))

Tags: node.js, geolocation, coordinates, latitude-longitude

Given a point with coordinates (long, lat) and given 4 edge-points of a rectangle with coordinates (long1, lat1), (long2, lat2), (long3, lat3), (long4, lat4).

How can I check, if the point is within the rectangle on a sphere (e.g. the rectangle is probably not "flat")?

The trivial check if a point is within a rectangle is clear to me but I think not correct if we assume the point and rectangle is on a earth.

Do you have any suggestions or solutions? I need to find a solution using NodeJS. Maybe there is a Framework for such tasks?

Comment: How large are such rectangles? How north and south are you? How precise you want to be? less than 500km, under 72 degree latitude: cartesiam math is enough (see UTM)

Comment: That varies. A user can zoom out and in within the earth map and the rectangle is the "map" itself. How can we implement it differently - using euclidean math?

Comment: Which projection? In other way, you may already have constant longitude on some side, and maybe also constant latitude, which simplify the calculations. But if the rectangle is the window itself, ... how do you calculate x,y from lat/long? Just calculate x,y also for the point and check if it is within the screen boundaries (and screen is cartesian/euclidean). [for me "cartesian": coordinates with perpendicular axes in an euclidean space, so yes, with Euclidean math]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at the very useful [geolib](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib), this supports checking if a point is in a polygon: [isPointInPolygon](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib#ispointinpolygonpoint-polygon), which should suffice for your needs:

```js
const point = { latitude: 51.5125, longitude: 7.485 };
const polygon = [
    { latitude: 51.5, longitude: 7.4 },
    { latitude: 51.555, longitude: 7.4 },
    { latitude: 51.555, longitude: 7.625 },
    { latitude: 51.5125, longitude: 7.625 },
];

console.log(geolib.isPointInPolygon(point, polygon))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/geolib@3.3.1/lib/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm, I checked the code, but thats also only a trivial check within the function of "isPointInPolygon". The problem is, the rectangle is on earth / sphere and therefore "not" a real rectangle.

I assume, that this method is not correct, or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: The method will determine if the point is within a polygon on the earth's surface. If the polygon represents a rectangle, it will be a rectangle in polar coordinates, e.g. latitude, longitude, and so not a "real" rectangle in 3D space. However, if your goal is to determine whether a point is within a specified area of the earth's surface it should work very well.